# npm publish only if changed in angular monorepo

Tags: angular, npm, monorepo

I have an angular monorepo with an "app" and a library, which is published as it's own npm package. This is done automatically on a CI environment. Until now, the library and the app have been separate and have had separate build jobs. Now that they are built together, I'm facing the problem that the lib is being published with every build (every change to `master`), even though the change might have been (and most likely is) in the app.

**Is there a straightforward way to only publish an npm package if it's contents have changed since the last time it was published?**

If I run `npm info <the-package>` there's a `.shasum` and `.integrity` checksum and I was hoping I could compare these to the same values when running `npm publish <directory> --dry-run`. Unfortunately, these commands result in different checksums, even though the contents of the packages are exactly the same. **

** to verify this, I compared the contents of the published tarball to a freshly built dist/ version of the lib. A `diff -r` over both directories reveal no differences.

**Update**

Due to lack of a better idea, I hacked together a manual solution in bash (since the publishing of my lib happens in a bash script anyway). Since in my case every release is tagged, I get the last tagged commit and check if anything has changed in the lib since then. This is by no means a good solution and you probably shouldn't use it but in case it helps someone:

```
PATH_TO_LIB='./projects/the-lib'

# find the last tagged commit and assume it was the last release
TAG=$(git describe --abbrev=0)
COMMIT=$(git rev-list -n 1 $TAG)

# check if anything changed in the lib since the last release
CHANGED=$(git diff --name-only HEAD $COMMIT $PATH_TO_LIB)
if [ ! -n "$CHANGED" ]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

There are a few obvious improvements that I don't really care to solve right now:

- the script should ignore commits that were tagged for another reason than a release
- the last release should be stored somehow, otherwise there's no guarantee that you're actually checking the last release since the last publishing of the lib
- it might make sense to ignore certain types of changes that don't warrant a new release

Answer (score 1):

Since npm@8 there is a new command `diff`. I think it should solve the problem.

> https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-diff

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';

exec(`cd ${yourPackageFolder} && npm diff --diff-name-only=true`, (err, stdout)=>{
  if( stdout !== '\n'){
    // execute publish command
  }
})
```